# PHPUnit, Selenium Basic Test Fails with Fatal Error

Tags: php, selenium, phpunit, tostring

I am running PHP 5.3.6 and the latest version of PHPUnit from Github. When I copy example 17.1 from the docs, it suffers a fatal error when the assertTitle fails. I get this error message:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function toString() on a non-object in <path>/phpunit/phpunit-selenium/PHPUnit/Extensions/SeleniumTestCase.php on line 1041
```

When I change the assertion to pass, PHPUnit runs just fine.

I dug up the line and this is the snippet :

```
protected function onNotSuccessfulTest(Exception $e)
    {
        if ($e instanceof PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException) {
            $buffer  = 'Current URL: ' . $this->drivers[0]->getLocation() .
                       "\n";
            $message = $e->getComparisonFailure()->toString();
```

$e->getComparisonFailure() returns NULL, not an object. What am I doing incorrectly?

UPDATE:

I found the reason for the failure, although a fix isn't on my horizon yet.

On line 92 of PHPUnit/Framework/Constraint.php, it calls using

`$this->fail($other,$description)`

which is defined as:

`protected function fail($other, $description, PHPUnit_Framework_ComparisonFailure $comparisonFailure = NULL)`

Since no PHPUnit_Framework_ComparisonFailure is passed, `NULL` is passed on line 141 of PHPUnit/Framework/Constraint.php

> throw new PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException(
>             $failureDescription,
>             $comparisonFailure
>           );

which is fetched by getComparisonFailure() which is supposed to return an object, as described above.

Any more ideas?

Comment: Your saying the default, copy-paste, example of phpunit-selenium has a bug when the only assertion in it fails which when copy and pasted should fail?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace `$message = $e->getComparisonFailure()->toString();` with `$message = $e->getComparisonFailure()->exceptionToString;`

It works fine for me

Comment: that doesn't work for me because the object returned by $e->getComparisonFailure is NULL, not an object with "exceptionToString" as a method.

Comment: I changed it to exceptionToString from exceptionToString() and it worked. Is this a bug in PHPUnit that requires a pull request?

Answer (score 3):

This problem relates to [issue #66](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/issues/66) on the PHPUnit-Selenium project on Github. I've made one commit that fixes this problem and one that fixes the ["setCustomMessage()" problem](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-selenium/issues/67) which Matthew mentioned. I think both problems where introduced by [one commit in PHPUnit 3.6](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/commit/7b37221b785dd5aeda8794e8ffdcbfd8cf3aad7b)

```
$message = $e->getComparisonFailure()->toString();
```

Where changed to

```
// ?: Is "comparison failure" set and therefore an object? (fixes issue #66)
if(is_object($e->getComparisonFailure())) {
    // -> Comparison failure is and object and should therefore have the toString method
    $message = $e->getComparisonFailure()->toString();
}
else {
    // -> Comparison failure is not an object. Lets use exception message instead
    $message = $e->getMessage();
}
```

And at the end of onNotSuccessfulTest():

```
$e->setCustomMessage($buffer);
```

Where changed to:

```
// ?: Does the setCustomMessage method exist on the exception object? (fixes issue #67)
if(method_exists($e, 'setCustomMessage')) {
    // -> Method setCustomMessage does exist on the object, this means we are using PHPUnit 
    //    between 3.4 and 3.6
    $e->setCustomMessage($buffer);
}
else {
    // -> Method setCustomerMessages does not exist on the object, must make a new exception to 
    //    add the new message (inc. current URL, screenshot path, etc)
    $e = new PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException($buffer, $e->getComparisonFailure());
}
```

Hopefully both changes will be accepted into the PHPUnit-Selenium project. At least it fixed the problems I where having with the latest updates for PHPUnit and PHPUnit-Selenium from PEAR.

Answer (score 1):

I replaced `$message = $e->getComparisonFailure()->toString();` to be:

```
if($e->getComparisonFailure() == NULL)
{
    $message = $e;
}
else
{
    $message = $e->getComparisonFailure()->toString();
}
```

I also reverted PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException back to 3.5.3 so it has `setCustomMessage()`